# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\int_{0}^{x}\cos u^2 du}{6\sin^{-1}x-6x-x^3}$

Tags: limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\int_{0}^{x}\cos u^2\,du}{6\sin^{-1}x-6x-x^3}$

This is a zero by zero form.Apply LH Rule,$=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x^2 }{\frac{6}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-6-3x^2}$

This is still zero by zero form,But if i apply LH Rule again,it does not give me answer $\dfrac{2}{9}$.

Comment: Most of times LHR will complicate things. Taylor Expansion will be a better option.

Comment: As it turns out, both the numerator and the denominator are $O(x^5)$ as $x \to 0$. Thus, you would have to use L'Hopital's Rule $5$ times before you will get a limit that isn't in the form $0/0$. Things will get very messy if you do things this way.

Comment: @JimmyK4542. I suppose that I was typing when your comment came. Sorry. Good observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\int_{0}^{x}\cos x^2dx}{6\sin^{-1}(x)-6x-x^3}\;,$$ Now Using $\bf{L,Hopital\; Rule}$

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x^2}{\frac{6}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-6-3x^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos x^2}{x^4}\right)\times \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^4}{6\left(1-x^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-6-3x^2}$$

Using $$\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos y}{y^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{6} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^4}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Now using Series expansion. for $$\displaystyle (1-x)^{-n} = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+........$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{6} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^4}{\left\{1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3}{8}x^4+.....\right\}-1-\frac{x^2}{2}} = \frac{2}{9}$$

So we get

Comment: Nice solution, indeed ! I did not expect that pure LHR would require to be applied five times. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's very short starting from the power series development of $\arcsin x$, and using equivalents:
$$\arcsin x= x +\frac12\frac{x^3}3+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\frac{x^5}5+o(x^5), $$
hence $$6\arcsin x -6x-x^3\sim_0\color{red}{\frac{9x^5}{20}}.$$

In the numerator,$\;\displaystyle\int_0^x \cos u^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u\;$ is the antiderivative of $\;\cos x^2\;$ that vanishes at $x=0$. As $\;\cos x^2=1-\dfrac{x^4}2+o(x^4)$, we have:
$$x-\int_0^x \cos u^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u=x-\Bigl(x-\frac{x^5}{10}\Bigr)+o(x^5)\sim_0 \color{red}{\frac{x^5}{10}}.$$

$$\text{Finally:}\hskip10em\frac{x-\int_0^x \cos u^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu u}{6\arcsin x -6x-x^3}\sim_0\frac{\dfrac{x^5}{10}}{\dfrac{9x^5}{20}}=\color{red}{\frac 29}.\hskip10em $$